# Query-clicks per 5 minutes

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am building a report to identify the number of visitors that click on specific buttons on my site.  After analyzing my logs I'm finding that visitors will click the same button multiple times (sometimes up to 10 times) within a minute or two, which totally skews the results.

I am trying to create a query that will count each visitor (by ip) only once within a 5 minute timeframe.  I have come up with the following, which gives me the total count, but I can't seem to find the right combination that will break it down into chunks of time. (datetime is of type *date*)

```
SELECT count(ip), ip, link, datetime  FROM `clicks` group by ip, link
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish this, or am I thinking about this incorrectly?  I suppose I could group it by day if necessary, but I would really like to break it down more granularly if possible.

Any pointers in the right direction will be much appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't the 'datetime' column be type `DATETIME`, not `DATE`? Can you provide an example of the input and desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want counts of IPs per 5 minute interval today, try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(ip) ipcount,dt FROM
(
    SELECT
    ip,(datetime - INTERVAL MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime),300)) SECOND dt
    FROM `clicks`
    WHERE datetime >= (DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND)
) A
GROUP BY dt;
```

The expression `DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND` is midnight today

```
mysql> select DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND;
+---------------------------------+
| DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND |
+---------------------------------+
| 2012-06-05 00:00:00             |
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Your addition only selects data from the past 5 minutes, whereas I am looking for visits from the entire day, but grouped and counted in 5 minute periods.  For example, if someone clicks the link now, then again in 10 minutes, I would like both clicks to show up in their own row.